# Reconstruction of a Signal from Sub Sampled Spectrum by Compressed Sensing

Tags: matlab, fourier-transform, python, compressive-sensing, inverse-problem

**Context**

Attempting to reproduce an illustrative example of compressive sampling from [Candes-Wakin 2008](https://authors.library.caltech.edu/10092/1/CANieeespm08.pdf). Specifically, the L1 recovery of a sparse signal shown on pg 5 in Fig. 2.
Using my code (below), results in ~12 - 20% error rates for exact reconstruction whereas the example seems to suggest we should get closer to 0%.

**Question**

Where does my implementation go wrong? Perhaps it's i) the order of sampling indices first, followed by inverse dct or ii) the [ECOS](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/ecos_ecc.pdf) solver that cvxpy invokes (instead of a more appropriate solver?)

Note: Fig 2 in Candes-Wakin suggests reconstruction from complex valued Fourier coefficients, whereas I use discrete cosine transform along the lines of Rish-Grabarnik section 3.2 in [their book](https://doc.lagout.org/science/0_Computer%20Science/2_Algorithms/Sparse%20Modeling_%20Theory%2C%20Algorithms%2C%20and%20Applications%20%5BRish%20%26%20Grabarnk%202014-12-05%5D.pdf) (link from Prof. Rish's [website](https://sites.google.com/site/irinarish/books))

**Code**
numpy (1.20.x), scipy, cvxpy (1.1.14)

````
import numpy as np
import scipy.fftpack as spfft
import cvxpy as cvx
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def set_signal(low: int = -1, high: int = 1, n: int = 10) -> np.ndarray:
    """Return a bounded uniform random vector in R^n."""
    s = np.random.uniform(low=low, high=high, size=(n, 1))
    return s


def sparsify_signal(s: np.ndarray, n_sparse: int = 1) -> np.ndarray:
    """Set random n_sparse many elements of s to zero."""
    if not isinstance(s, np.ndarray):
        s = np.array(s)
    indices_to_zero = np.random.choice(a=len(s), size=n_sparse, replace=False)
    s[indices_to_zero] = 0
    return s


# PARAMS
N_dim = 512  # real-dim of where original signal lives
S_dim = 30  # support size: num non-zero entries in original signal
null_dim = N_dim - S_dim
m_samples = 60  # alternative: S_sparse * log(N_dim), for some log base...
delta = 1e-5  # lower bound nonzero solution terms; used in post-opt analysis

# INITIALIZE
X = set_signal(n=N_dim)  # won't reconstruct this, but sparse version of it
X_sparse = sparsify_signal(s=X, n_sparse=null_dim)
yt = spfft.dct(X_sparse, norm='ortho')   # project sparse signal to (real) Fourier

# PROJECT AND SAMPLE
sample_indices = np.random.choice(N_dim, m_samples, replace=False)  # fix coordinates to sample
sample_indices.sort()  # plotting convenience
yt_sample = yt[sample_indices]  # restrict sparse signal to random sample indices
yt_sample = yt_sample.squeeze()
# Discrete cosine transform as matrix representation
A = spfft.dct(np.identity(N_dim), norm='ortho', axis=0)
A = A[sample_indices]

# Optimization
vx = cvx.Variable(N_dim)  # reconstruct a signal in N_dim space
objective = cvx.Minimize(cvx.norm(vx, 1))
constraints = [A@vx == yt_sample]  # constraint in Fourier space
opt_problem = cvx.Problem(objective, constraints)
result = opt_problem.solve(verbose=True)

# Summarize optimization
print("status: {}".format(opt_problem.status))
optimal_x = vx.value.reshape(N_dim, 1)  # unsqueeze

# Number of nonzero elements in the solution (its cardinality or diversity).
nnz_l1 = (np.absolute(optimal_x) > delta).sum()
E = np.isclose(optimal_x, X_sparse)
E_support = np.isclose(optimal_x[sample_indices], X_sparse[sample_indices])
# we could computed L2 error, but the claim is 100% on the nose reconstruction...probabilistically
error_rate = 1 - (E.sum() / N_dim)
S_error_rate = 1 - (E_support.sum() / m_samples)
print('Found a feasible x in R^{} that has {} nonzeros.'.format(N_dim, nnz_l1))
print('Reconstruction error rate is %0.2f' % error_rate)
print('Support Reconstruction error rate is %0.2f' % S_error_rate)

# PLOT
plt.plot(X_sparse, '.', color='b', label='original sparse signal')
plt.plot(optimal_x, '.', color='g', label='approximation')
plt.legend()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're after the problem:

$$\begin{aligned}
\arg \min_{\boldsymbol{x}} \quad & {\left\| \boldsymbol{x} \right\|}_{1}  \\
\text{subject to} \quad & \hat{F} \boldsymbol{x} = \boldsymbol{y}
\end{aligned}$$

Where $ \hat{F} $ is a sub set of rows of a unitary matrix.
In the case of the example of [Emmanuel J. Candes, Michael B. Wakin - An Introduction To Compressive Sampling](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4472240) it is sub sampled [DFT Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFT_matrix).

The actual analysis of the example is given by [Robust Uncertainty Principles: Exact Signal Reconstruction from Highly Incomplete Frequency Information](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0409186). In this case we have 3 main parameters:

1. The Number of Samples ($ N $) - 256 (In their code 512).
2. The Number of Non Zero Samples ($ \left| T \right| $) - Changes from 2 to 32.
3. The Number of Given Frequency Samples ($ \left| \Omega \right| $) - Changes from 4 to 64.

I solved the problem using my solution to [How Can L1 Norm Minimization with Linear Equality Constraints (Basis Pursuit / Sparse Representation) Be Formulated as Linear Programming](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1639716).

The results I get are:

[image]

Which are according to their numerical examples.
The code is available at my [StackExchange Codes Signal Processing Q78143 GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\Q78143` folder).

Comment: thank you -- if I'm reading your code right, one of the key elements of your solution is to i) use a discrete fourier transform (not a dct as alluded to in the Rishik reference) and ii) apply equality constraints to the corresponding real and imaginary separately as in [this line](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes/blob/c217b42cbceff64f6c2514c980481c9ad33d6784/SignalProcessing/Q78143/Q78143.m#L84) .

Comment: You could use the DCT matrix if you build it as an orthogonal matrix. Since it is a real transform you won’t need to do the trick I did.